# How to implement pipe when the parent function receive different arguments

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I'm new to functional programming and have a question regarding pipe.

Say I have the following function:

```
const modifyArr = R.curry((i, newValue, arr) => 
                    Object.assign([], arr, {[i]: newValue}))
```

This function change an array's value on a specific index.

Now, I want to use this function twice (with pipe) in order to implement swap between two element in the array.

I cannot figured out how to write it. This is what I got:

```
const swap = (arr, a, b) => 
                R.pipe(modifyArr(b, arr[a], modifyArr(a, arr[b])))
```

Notice that the curried version of modifyArr (after receiving two arguments) expects an array, but I'm passing 3 arguments to the swap function.

How can I use pipe where my parent function receive a different arguments than the first function in the pipe?

Thanks.

Comment: You can't swap like that, the value at one index should be store in a variable first or you'll get the other value twice!

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Actually it should work given the order of argument evaluation in JS, but it's very confusing indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that your functions are curried, you can simply partially apply the former arguments before doing the piping:

```
const swap = (arr, a, b) => R.pipe(modifyArr(a, arr[b]), modifyArr(b, arr[a]))(arr);
```

Comment: Wow, so simple. Thanks a lot!!